# tank auth logouts unexpectedly

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2, tankauth

I'm using tank auth for my project but while working the session expires unexpectedly.

```
    public function __construct()
{
    parent:: __construct();


    $this->load->model("stulib");

    $this->load->library("Gen");
    $this->load->model('tank_auth/users','users');
    $this->load->library('tank_auth');
    $this->title='Angel';
    $this->user_id=$this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
    $this->school_id=$this->users->get_school();
    $this->school_name=$this->users->get_school_name($this->school_id);
    $this->yesterday=$this->studentlib->yesterday();

    if(!$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in())
      die("No access rio!");

}
```

That's my controller. I check is_logged_in only there at the constructor for the controller.

EDIT:

- I'm  storing session in database
- I'm not using any ajax request
- I use twitter bootstrap framework

Comment: What browser is this in?

Comment: Chrome. I can work for few minutes i think but the period is very uneven it would logout at any time.

Comment: Are you store the sessions in the db?

Comment: ya I'm storing it in database

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Tank Auth and CodeIgniter 2.1 .

You can find detailed explanation and solution here

http://www.hiretheworld.com/blog/tech-blog/codeigniter-session-race-conditions

These links could also help you:
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/199753/#962141

http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/203821/#951378